# Where should I ask a question about routing options for Gmail in G-Suite?

Tags: discussion

I posted [this question on webapps.se](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117003/how-to-automate-prevention-of-outbound-emails-to-specific-addresses-from-gsuite) which covers implementation/features/options of GSuite/Gmail. I understand webapps.se may not be best for it.

I *think* it should be here on ServerFault, but could argue it should be on StackOverflow as it is potentially about the Gsuite APIs too.

Is this the best place to put it, or is there somewhere else in the StackExchange network?

Comment: For the record, I've asked the question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/911710/how-to-automate-prevention-of-outbound-emails-to-specific-email-addresses-in-g-s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GDPR compliance by itself is largely a legal issue which has no place here (and likely anywhere else on SE). This would include questions of the type "I want to do X. Will this be enough to be GDPR compliant?".

However, the linked question is concerned with a technical problem (just motivated by GDPR) and I believe it could be topical here. That said, I could imagine that this could also be asked on SO if this would be part of a larger CRM environment.

Comment: Great thanks - I'll make sure my question is clear on it being about the technical side, not the GDPR side.

Answer (score 1):

GDPR is not really a technology problem. It's a legal issue as Sven says, and its also a *business* (as in not just IT) process issue.

There isn't "one weird trick to being GDPR compliant" that anyone can tell you; rather your business needs to be assessing its own specific behaviours (e.g. as you're talking about G Suite apps can *you* get legal assurance from Google about where data is stored, how its processed, etc), carrying out risk assessments of its own specific procedures and drawing up its own specific actions as a result of that.

Nobody here could reliably answer a question by saying "click this button on a google settings page somewhere and you're magically insured against GDPR issues".

You need to have various policies around the capture, use, storage and destruction of personal data and this applies whether or not that data is stored on a server or on bits of paper inside a physical filing cabinet.

If anything, this is a legal issue imo: can google give you assurance that it will process data you store there in accordance with your policies.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I think the title of this question was badly worded. What I really mean is "where should I ask a question about Gmail routing options within GSuite". The GDPR piece is irrelevant - I've edited the question title accordingly.